# How can I open an application using python on macOS?

Tags: python, macos

I want to open an application on my mac computer through pycharm using python. I assume I will need to use some kind of library but I am not sure.

Comment: `os.system("open " + app_path)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, great thanks. I will try

Comment: @OneCricketeer would the code just be os.exec("open" + /user/safari) ?

Comment: You don't need to use string concatenation if you have a hard-coded string. And you can run the same in a terminal, outside Python, to test it

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ok, so I can have it all in one string.